# Storing access Token in WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF project, I'm implementing a login function. The goal is to securely store the API access token so that it can be retrieved whenever an API call is made. I'm using Properties.Settings.Default to store the token, as shown in the example below. However, I'm concerned about the safety of this approach. Is it a recommended way to store the token securely? Additionally, I'm wondering if there are any libraries available that can help encrypt the token and store it within the application, enabling the user to remain logged in even when they relaunch the program.

```
// Storing the access token
Properties.Settings.Default.AccessToken = "api-access-token";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

// Retrieving the access token
string accessToken = Properties.Settings.Default.AccessToken;
```

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to improve the security of storing and retrieving the access token in my application.

Comment: the best way is to use obfuscation app the encrypt strings in your code such as .net reactor.

Comment: Obfuscation doesn't protect secrets.

Answer (score 0):

The settings data within the user scope is stored in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\<ProjectName>` folder.

To **improve** the security the user itself can use build-in [file-encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-encryption) (if the file-system is NTFS) where he can control which user is allowed to access the decrypted version of the file.

Another option is to use the build-in [Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection) where you can encrypt data on `MachineScope` or `UserScope` (you want here `UserScope`) and it is up to your app to encrypt/decrypt the data on writing/reading from the settings so that only the current user is able to decrypt the data.

Both options are secure if noone other knows the credentials for that user account and there is no spyware running in the user session crawling for data, because any process running in that user context is able to decrypt the data/file.

Comment: I actually don't want any user to be able to access the token. Is there another way to achieve this? I was looking at CredentialManagement but it also doesn't seem like the solution I want. I was also thinking of encrypting the token but I would need a passphrase to decrypt, and storing the passphrase in config file or some other place defeats the purpose of encrypting the token.

Comment: There has to be at least one user (account) which can access the token but it does not has to be the current user. You can built a web-api that is running as a service on that machine with a special user account and the web-api is limited to the local machine. That service user can access the token which is protected like I said in my answer. Any other user has to ask the local running web-api to get the data from there